# How to sum up property string length by ID using PHP in a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to sum up the character count(total string length) of all the characters contained in the various "info" properties by "user_id".
I am trying to have a situation where **USER-ID A001 has 300 total characters in INFO**

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Below is my code snippet:

```
{
    "main": {
        "request": "40"
    },
    "data": {
        "page": 1,
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "user_id": "A001",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Ugon Charles",
                "user_id": "A007",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Mary Ann",
                "user_id": "A004",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Mary Ann",
                "user_id": "A004",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "user_id": "A001",
                "info": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "user_id": "A001",
                "info": "Ut enim ad minima veniam"
            
            }
            
            
        ]
    }
}
```

MY PHP

```
foreach ($data['data']['posts'] as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr->strlen($data['data']['posts']['info']) as $obj) {
        ${$obj->user_id} += $obj->info;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$arr->strlen($data['data']['posts']['info'])` supposed to mean?

Comment: What are `$obj->value_type` and `$obj->value` supposed to be? How is that related to the data you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an associative array to hold the results, with the `user_id` values as the keys.

```
$lengths = [];

foreach ($data['data']['posts'] as $post) {
    $userid = $post['user_id'];
    if (isset($lengths[$userid])) {
        $lengths[$userid] += strlen($post['info']);
    } else {
        $legths[$userid] = strlen($post['info']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood what you want is to get the total count of each post "info" length (or total characters) and the general total count of all those.

```
$data = json_decode($a,true);
$total = 0;
foreach ($data['data']['posts'] as $key => $arr) {
    $data['data']['posts'][$key]['count'] = strlen($arr['info']);
    $total += strlen($arr['info']);
}
$data['data']['total_count'] = $total;
echo 'total count is '.$data['data']['total_count'].PHP_EOL;
```

this outputs: `total count is 647`